# Implementando método para hacer busquedas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, linq, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework code first, app windows forms.
Tengo un método implementado en la capa de persistencia el cual no se como usarlo en la UI, resulta que solo le voy a pasar un parámetro a la vez, les muestro mi implementacion.

Persistencia

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
    {
        var result = (from p in Context.Proveedores
                      where ((!codigo.HasValue) || (p.ProveedorId == codigo.Value)) &&
                      ((nombre == null) || (p.RazonSocial.Contains(nombre)))
                      select new ProveedorExtend()
                      {
                          Id = p.ProveedorId,
                          Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
                      }).ToList();
        return result;          
    }
```

ServicioDominio

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
    {
        return _proveedorRespository.SelectList(codigo, nombre);
    }
```

ServicioAplicacion
Tengo una clase DTO por el motivo que voy usar una lista generica donde voy a cargar datos de diferentes entidades que busque por medio del filtro.

```
public class DGVBusquedaDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

#

```
public IEnumerable<DGVBusquedaDto> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
    {
        IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> _proveedor = _sdproveedor.SelectList(codigo, nombre);
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ProveedorExtend, DGVBusquedaDto>());
        IEnumerable<DGVBusquedaDto> listDto = 
            config.CreateMapper().Map<IEnumerable<DGVBusquedaDto>>(_proveedor);
        return listDto;
    }
```

UI

```
DGVBusquedaDto filter = new DGVBusquedaDto()
                    {
                        Id = Helper.InputBoxInt,
                    };
                    listDGV = _repositoryProveedor.SelectList(filter);
DGVBusquedaDto filter = new DGVBusquedaDto()
                    {
                        Descripcion = Helper.InputBoxValor,
                    };
                    listDGV = _repositoryProveedor.SelectList(filter)
```

Cuando implemento el método me pide los dos parámetros, solo debo pasarle uno a la vez o en todo caso los dos pero algo como esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la capa de UI debes de utilizar la firma o signatura de la función definida en la capa de Persistencia. Tienes dos alternativas:

Utilizarla directamente desde la UI:

```
listDGV = _repositoryProveedor.SelectList(filter.Id, filter.Descripcion);
```

Crear una sobrecarga de la función en la capa de persistencia que acepte un argumento de tipo Filter:

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(DGVBusquedaDto filter)
{
    return SelectList(filter.Id, filter.Descripcion);
}
```

Comment: Puede ser public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(ProveedorExtend filter) el problema es como sería la query?

Comment: La query ya existe en el primer método que muestras en tu pregunta. El  método que te propongo lo que hace es simplemente llamar a ese método con los parámetros adecuados, no es necesario hacer nada más.